# Why Can't I Insert a child to the selected Node?

Tags: extjs

I have tried from multiple examples but I can't see to add any children deeper then the first children from the root.

```
// This Works
var treeNode = Ext.getCmp('projectTree').getRootNode();
treeNode.expandChildren(true); // Optional: To see what happens
treeNode.appendChild({
    name: 'Child 4',
    leaf: true
});

// This Doesn't work
Ext.getCmp('projectTree').getSelectionModel( ).getSelectedNode().insertChild({
        name: 'Child 6',
        leaf: true
});

// This Doesn't work
Ext.getCmp('projectTree').getChildAt(0).insertChild({
        name: 'Child 6',
        leaf: true
});
```

Comment: Because you made up both of those methods. `getSelectedNode` isn't a method on `Ext.selection.TreeModel`, `getChildAt` is not a method on `Ext.tree.Panel`.

Comment: What Evan said. Try looking at what errors you are getting.

Comment: I am new to Sencha and get confused between the different Tree elements.  What is the proper way to add a grandchild to the tree?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that your code seems to be from an older version of ExtJS. Try the official documents from Sencha page. Assuming you have successfully get the selected node, this is how I add grandchild node (refer to your other question):

```
selectedNode.childNodes[0].appendChild({
    text: 'Grand Child 3',
    leaf: true
});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1rg